# How to setup AirPlay with TV connected through ethernet and laptop connected to an access point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, airplay

Good day! I am a newbie in networking and this question might be not a good fit for such place, but I'll still give it a try.

I own a TV which supports AirPlay and which is connected to the router an internet provider gave me. This router is bad even for short distances in my apartment, so as I've had a Unifi Access Point, I've decided to use it to delivery hight quality WiFi. Everything works great, except now there is a problem that my computer thinks that it is in different networks with TV. Is there a way to let them know about each other and stream content through the AirPlay?

So, as I have no idea where to start my investigation, here is the schema of the connections. Would be grateful for any help.

[image]

Comment: Best guess is you have the UniFi set up as a gateway/router rather than an access point, so it's providing its own DHCP service. Check the manual for 'access point' mode, then let the ISP's router do DHCP

Comment: This UniFi access point doesn't have its own DHCP, thus I had to use provider's router for this.

Comment: Then there would be no reason for the subnets to be different. You need to look at what the DHCP server is giving to which device.

Comment: Yes, their subnets are same. My ip is not changing whether I'm connected to an access point or router. But when I'm connecting my laptop directly to router through the WiFi, AirPlay starts working. I have no idea why.

Comment: Then I've no idea, sorry. It's got to be some setting in the UniFI [though why that would be a default defies logic].